# How to define a function in an interface in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class, interface

I have the following problem for which I did not find a working solution.
I have an interface in my Angular Application:

```
export interface Person {
    forename: string;
    surname: string;
}
```

How would I have to define a function named `getFullName()` with following implementation:

```
getFullName(){
  return this.forename + " " + this.surname;
}
```

I tried it directly in the interface with the function as key but it did not work...

Comment: An interface cannot have implementation, you could only declare the *existence* of such a method (`getFullName(): string`). For implementation, you need a class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So if I would have an interface, I would have to generate a class for that interface if I had a function signature in my interface? Then why would I want an interface? So, class would be a better idea if you have functions?

Comment: You can only have the actual function in the implementation, class-based or otherwise, not the interface. Interfaces do not exist in the emitted JS, so cannot have implementation.

Comment: I think I understood, an interface is like an abstract class.

Comment: No, explicitly not: [*"Unlike an interface, an abstract class may contain implementation details for its members."*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function signature `() => string` to represent a function which takes 0 arguments and returns a string.

```js
export interface Person {
    forename: string;
    surname: string;
    getFullName: () => string;
}
```

You can't define the implementation in the interface though.

To create a class that implements the interface you can do the following:

```js
class MyPerson implements Person {
  constructor(public forename: string, public surname: string) { }
 
  getFullName() {
    return this.forename + " " + this.surname;
  } 
}
```

You possibly don't need the interface Person in this case - instead you could just use the class.

Comment: And where would I put the implementation?

Comment: @Opat updated. You should use an interface where you want to declare that objects are of a certain type and therefore can be used in a certain way. For example - if you have a few different class implementations (Student, Teacher for example) that have `Person` properties. If you just want to create person objects, then don't bother with an interface.

Comment: Ahh, i think now I understand. An interface is like an abstract class, or am I wrong?

Comment: It's a similar concept. The key difference is usually that interfaces don't contain implementations and that you can implement multiple interfaces (where normally abstract classes can contain implementations and a class can only extend one abstract class). These aren't concrete rules for every language though - but they are true of TypeScript. There are a ton of resources out there on abstract classes vs interfaces, so I won't try to rehash them here but have a look on google for some better explanations.